# Custom TinyMCE Editor in wordpress frontend

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm using Page Layout Builder (http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-layout-builder/) It Adds custom buttons to the tinymce editor in the wordpress admn section.

What should i do to get the same tinymce editor in the frontend?

Comment: Do you need it to save data and do what that plugin does only publicly? Security will end up being the biggest part of the project.

Comment: yes i just need to update the post or page. Only the users with permission would be able to access this frontend editor. Still the security issue can rise ?